# Python Run at startup

Tags: python, windows, pysimplegui

I am working on a small project using python and pysimplegui . Here my application needs to have a option "Run at start up" which when checked would automatically run my application during windows starts up. Also I would like to know how can I put my application to the system tray. Like if I click on the minimize button , it'll go to the system tray.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To Run On Startup

1. Create shortcut of your application & copy it.
2. Press win + R
   [Run Command: shell:startup, Hit ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBQQf.png)

3.[And paste the shortcut in this folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5rEh.png)

To Add In System Try

1. [Go to the SETTINGS window and choose System.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tVTB.png)
2. [In the SYSTEM window, select Notifications & actions. Here you can select the option that reads “Select which icons appear on the taskbar”[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FPp2.png)
3. [In the SELECT WHICH ICONS APPEAR ON THE TASKBAR window, you can turn on or off the icons in whichever way you prefer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbmiH.png)

Comment: Hello, I was actually looking for a solution that would require minimal work from the user side , basically automating this whole process , using python. Is there any way?